# Javascript stop/reset timer If Popup window is closed

Tags: javascript, timer, popup

Hey guys i'm new to JavaScript but i would like to accomplish something

I have this JavaScript timer script and i would like to open a popup & start the timer on a button click and also reset and stop the timer if the popup i have opened is closed.

This is my timer code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
var isWaiting = false;
var isRunning = true;
var seconds = 15;
var countdownTimer;
var finalCountdown = false;

function GameTimer() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
    }
    document.getElementById('waiting_time').innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-spin fa-spinner'></i> " + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
                    document.getElementById('waiting_time').innerHTML = "" ;
                    document.getElementById('step').innerHTML = "<button class='button' onclick='window.location.reload();return false;'><font color='#8d9d29'><i class='fa fa-arrow-circle-right'></i> Next step</font></button>" ;
        if (finalCountdown) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        } else {
            finalCountdown = true;
        }

    } else {
        isWaiting = true;
        seconds--;

        if (seconds == 0) {
            seconds=seconds;}     


    }
}
countdownTimer = setInterval(GameTimer, 1000);
}//]]>  

</script>
```

And this checks if the popup has been closed

```
var child = window.open('http://google.com/','','toolbar=0,status=0,width=926,height=536');
    var timer = setInterval(checkChild, 500);
    function checkChild() {
        if (child.closed) {
            /// something 
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
     }
```

how can i merge these two snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really certain if this is what you're looking for. I don't know that I understood what it was that you needed.

I restructured the code just a little bit. The main thing is that I put the variables into a global object called `GameObject`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    var GameObject = {
        "isWaiting" : false,
        "isRunning" : true,
        "seconds" : 15,
        "finalCountdown" : false,
        "child" : null,
        "countdownTimer" : null,
        "gametimer" : null
    };

    function onButtonClick() {
        //Open the window
        GameObject.child = window.open('http://google.com/','','toolbar=0,status=0,width=926,height=536');

        //Start the window open check interval
        GameObject.gametimer = setInterval(function() {
            if (GameObject.child.closed) {
                /// something 
                clearInterval(GameObject.gametimer);
                clearInterval(GameObject.countdownTimer);
            }
        }, 500);

        //Start the game timer
        GameObject.countdownTimer = setInterval(GameTimer, 1000);
    }

    function GameTimer() {
        var minutes = Math.round((GameObject.seconds - 30) / 60);
        var remainingSeconds = GameObject.seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
        }
        document.getElementById('waiting_time').innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-spin fa-spinner'></i> " + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
        if (GameObject.seconds == 0) {
            document.getElementById('waiting_time').innerHTML = "" ;
            document.getElementById('step').innerHTML = "<button class='button' onclick='window.location.reload();return false;'><font color='#8d9d29'><i class='fa fa-arrow-circle-right'></i> Next step</font></button>" ;

            if (GameObject.finalCountdown) {
                clearInterval(GameObject.countdownTimer);
            } else {
                GameObject.finalCountdown = true;
            }

        } else {
            GameObject.isWaiting = true;
            GameObject.seconds--;

            if (GameObject.seconds == 0) {
                GameObject.seconds = GameObject.seconds;
            }
        }
    }
//]]>
</script>
```